# array scan preventing next string scan?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this code:

- I insert 4 numbers into an array.
- After I've inserted those, I want to check which two numbers are the biggest and which two are the smallest.
- Before doing this check, I want to ask the user whether they want to add a new number.
- This number would replace one of the other numbers.

The problem is that my code just stops after this line:

```
System.out.println("Do you wish to add another number [Y/N]?");
```

I never get to enter Y or N ("Yes/No").  However, this works if I remove the scans before it. The import statement that I use is `import.util.*;`  Any idea or helpful advice is appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

int[] array;
array = new int[4];

System.out.println("Enter nr1:");
array[0] = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter nr2:");
array[1] = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter nr3:");
array[2] = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter nr4:");
array[3] = sc.nextInt();  

System.out.println("Do you wish to add another number [Y/N]?");
String answer = sc.nextLine();


if ("N".equals(answer)){

    Arrays.sort(array);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    System.out.println("Samllest value: " + array[0]);
    System.out.println("Second smalles value: " + array[1]);
    System.out.println("Second biggest value: " + array[2]);
    System.out.println("Biggest value: " + array[3]);
}
```

Comment: It's because of `sc.nextInt();` You need to skip it or use `sc.nextLine()` and parse the result appropriately.

Comment: Java does not like to use the same Scanner for int and for String. Use a second Scanner for the nextLine() and it will work.

Comment: You simply call `sc.nextLine()` after calling `sc.nextInt()` to handle the end-of-line token, that's it.

Comment: @StefanNeubert: That is totally false. I just tried and java does not care.

Comment: @Lion: There is nothing wrong with the `nextInt` calls, I just tried and it worked fine.

Comment: Use sc.next() instead of sc.nextString().

Comment: @Kane- When you use `Scanner.nextInt()`, it does not consume the new line (or other delimiter) itself so the next token returned will typically be an empty string. Thus, you need to follow it with a `Scanner.nextLine()`. There is nothing wrong of course but care should be exercised while using it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be using `Scanner.next()` not `Scanner.nextLine()`.

Comment: 1+ since this works, but sometimes you need to call `nextLine()`, and then this won't work.

Comment: Fair enough, it was just the quickest answer to his question.

Comment: Used this solution now since this was a minor excersise I was doing. Thanks for the help! @Kane

Comment: You're welcome, @Nilsson. If you used the answer you should mark it as accepted so other people that come along will see the question has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Scanner#nextInt()` and similar methods do not handle the End-Of-Line token. One solution is to simply call `nextLine()` after calling `nextInt()` to handle and discard this token.

i.e.,

```
System.out.println("Enter nr1:");
array[0] = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter nr2:");
array[1] = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter nr3:");
array[2] = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter nr4:");
array[3] = sc.nextInt();  
sc.nextLine();

System.out.println("Do you wish to add another number [Y/N]?");
String answer = sc.nextLine();
```